# How to start a script after that the controller sends data to jsp

Tags: java, javascript, jsp, spring-mvc, controller

I have index.jsp. This jsp calls the controller:

```
@Controller
public class CustomerController {

    //Other code..
    //..
    String customerJSON = null;
    ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView("index", "customerJSON",  customerJSON);
    return model;
}
```

customerJSON is a string that contains JSON information.

Controller returns customerJSON to jsp.

Now, in jsp, I want to show customerJSON into an alert.

In jsp I add:

```
<script>
    var customer = "<c:out value='${customerJSON}'/>";
    alert(customer);
</script>
```

The problem is that, this alert, starts when the page is loaded and not when the controller returns to jsp.

How can I show the alert after controller call and not when the page is loaded?

Comment: can you more explicit, javascript will run only after its loaded by client(browser), but your value is written in jsp on server side when response is not even received by browser

Answer (score 0):

I would implement your controller method (and requestmapping) something like this:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/getCustomer")
public @ResponseBody Customer getCustomer() {
    Customer c = new Customer();
    //do whatever is needed to init customer data

    return c;
}
```

If you have jackson as dependency that will take care of json-serializing for you.

Then your javascript (using jquery) code could look something like this:

```
<script>
$.getJSON("getCustomer", data, function (result)      
{
   alert(result);
});
</script>
```